# Authorization error when attempting to download blob information from Azure

Tags: c#, azure, .net-4.5, windows-phone-8.1, azure-blob-storage

I have a Windows store app I am building a lite version for Windows Phone 8.1, these are both developed in C#.  I currently save a small text file to a blob to sync data between devices.  For the Windows store app, it works perfectly.  I can sync between my Surface Pro, Desktop, and laptop.  Now I am implementing this into my phone app but I am getting an authorization error

{Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.d__6`1.MoveNext()
Request Information
RequestID:2ee5de0a-0f2c-477f-92df-ba52cce3b6c0
RequestDate:Tue, 05 Aug 2014 20:11:25 GMT
StatusMessage:Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
}.

I know the usual fix for this is to check the workstation time, so i tried setting the phone time to UTC, different time zones etc.  None of it worked. It is getting frustrating because this is working perfectly everywhere but the phone app

Here is the code I am working with:

```
StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentials("<AccountName>", "<AccountKey>");

var account = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);

var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("synccontainer");
var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("MyBlob");

****Everything prior to here executes correctly, everything below will throw the error****

bool blockBlobExists = await container.GetBlockBlobReference("MyBlob").ExistsAsync();
await blockBlob.FetchAttributesAsync();
var bbProperties = blockBlob.Properties;
```

Comment: What's the value in `blobPath` variable?

Comment: It is the name of the blob

Comment: Can you check the time on the device? One of the reasons you would get authorization error is because of incorrect time on the device/computer. The other reason obviously is incorrect account key.

Comment: What type of an application is this? I mean, is it a Windows Phone Silverlight app? Or a universal app?

Comment: Just to throw an alternative into the mix - if you have doubts about using the Microsoft.WindowsAzure on a specific, try using the BlobStorage REST API -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135733.aspx

Comment: @Serdar Ozler, its a Windows Phone 8.1 app, not silverlight just a stand alone C# app.  My plan is to bring this app and its companion tablet app to a shared codebase after this release.

Comment: @SeanCocteau, I am avoiding using the REST API as I want to have a common code base between the 2 apps